# Tweaking YouTube playback and pre-cache

Tags: youtube

Is there any way to tweak the YouTube client caching feature?

I have this weird issue where some of the videos will have huge latency. It takes ages before the video starts caching. Now this becomes completely fatal, because the video will cache 10 seconds of playback, then stop (cause that should be enough, right?), but since the latency is bigger than 10 seconds it will get stuck. It's soo incredibly anoying and only happens with some videos.

Is it possible to somehow force the client to pre-cache the entire video?

P.S. This problem persists across operating systems and browsers. My connection is 120/10Mbit, with very low latency across the entire world.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out [here](http://lifehacker.com/preload-entire-youtube-videos-by-disabling-dash-playbac-1186454034) you just need to disable "Dash Playback". An easy way to do this is to install the "YouTube Center" browser plugin and just uncheck the corresponding setting in Settings -> Player.

[image: YouTube Center Dash Playback]